# Win7 Google Chrome caching Internet Connection Settings

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, registry, wininet

I have some code that runs in a Windows service and sets some proxy settings on a per-user basis.  Specifically it sets:

HKU[user sid]\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL

HKU[user sid]\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\EnableAutoProxyResultCache

HKU[user sid]\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\Connection Settings

For "locked down" users it sets:

AutoConfigURL=http://127.0.0.1:8888/wpad.dat

EnableAutoProxyResultCache=0

Connection Settings=1

For "unlocked" users it sets:

AutoConfigURL (deletes this key)

Connection Settings (deletes this key)

---

Everything works great on Windows XP, in IE, FireFox, and Chrome.  As soon as I restart any of those browsers, the new settings are used (uses the proxy or doesn't).

On Windows 7, everything works great in FireFox and IE, but not Chrome.  Chrome doesn't start using the new settings until one of the following happen:

1. I run inetcpl.cpl and click the OK button (don't need to change anything, but do need to click OK, not just Cancel)
2. I log-off and back on the Windows user account
3. I run IE (just running IE and closing it)

**I'm looking for a programatic way to reset this cache, whatever cache it is.**

What I've tried but hasn't worked:

1. Almost every "netsh" command option I can think of.
2. InternetSetOption() (see MSDN) with the proxy settings changed and refresh flags (using NULL as the hInternet handle)
3. Deleted the values under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\

---

Has anyone seen this caching issue and found a way to clear it?  If not, what info should I be looking for in general.  Is this a WinHTTP cache, TCP, IP, WinInet?  Even though it is only showing up in Google Chrome, I don't think it is an actual Chrome cache, I think it is at the OS level.

I know I should probably be using InternetSetOption instead of updating the registry directly, but that doesn't work from a service, and I've found some anti-virus programs that are causing issues with any desktop app level code (but they don't mind if my service updates things).  Not to mention that some of the settings above require admin/elevation to modify, even though all under HKCU.

Comment: superuser.com is the right place to go for this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a testing error, or an anomaly, calling this after setting the registry values does appear to work:

```
   InternetSetOption(NULL,INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED,NULL,0);
   InternetSetOption(NULL,INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH,NULL,0);
```